# How to write Flattened Pub/Sub data in real time in bigquery using Apache Beam using python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have to develop a pipeline using python that is listening to a pub/sub subscription, after getting an input the pipeline should take that input what pub/sub is providing and flatten that. After flattening the input it should create a schema that is to be provided dynamically as an input to my apache beam bigquery sink. On the basis of input Pub/Sub message, my code should be able to change the schema for the Bigquery tables if any changes take place in my bigquery schema. I can provide a json file which can be stored or update on GCS, to input the input_subscription, bigquery_output_table and some parameters, but providing the schema dynamically and inferring the schema from the input is a blocker for me. Please help me with it.

Comment: I have tried solution like : https://github.com/the-dagger/dataflow-dynamic-schema

Comment: Is your question on how to flatten Pub/Sub data using Apache Beam?

Comment: Yes, but with dynamic schema mutation

Comment: Would these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/pubsub-to-bigquery#expandable-1),[link2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/pubsub-to-bigquery) and [link3](https://medium.com/@vaibhav_85197/mutating-dynamic-fields-to-bigquery-using-cloud-dataflow-b8933f382dda) be helpful to you?

Comment: Thanks @kiranmathew, these would be very helpful but I'm new to JAVA and do not know anything else than python, is there something that can be used in python as well as there are many functions in apache beam that are exclusive to JAVA and aren't there in python?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using and a sample of the input Pub/Sub message format?